# Scale Animation not smooth in android on image view

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-imageview, scaleanimation

I have use **Scale Animation** for zooming an image in my app. It's working fine zoom image level proper which we want but my issue is when zooming the image not zoom **smoother**.
image size is 1.4 mb.

```
ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 2.5f,
                        1f, 2.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
                        1.05f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.05f);
  scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
  scaleAnimation.setDuration(400);
  img.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

Comment: check out my approch and try it.

Comment: ok i try it.. after some time @Ironman

Answer (score 3):

If your min sdk version is greater than 13 then you can try

```
img.animate().scaleX(2.5f).scaleY(2.5f).setDuration(400).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Android animations with `Zoom animation smoothly`  [**Here.**](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/#zoom_in)

You can custom them for making more smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Create **scale_up.xml**:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:fromXScale="1"
           android:fromYScale="1"
           android:toXScale="1.2"
           android:toYScale="1.2"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:duration="400"/>
</set>
```

and Use this way..

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_up);
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle_image)).startAnimation(animation );
```

It will give you smooth Animation.

> **Note :** make sure that to get smooth animation you have to set
>   `android:pivotX` and `android:pivoty` to half of screen.